# Valid Huffman Codes?

Tags: theory, huffman-code

I'm trying to solve a Huffman Coding problem, but I'm not completely sure I understand the topic completely. I am trying to figure out if the following are is a valid Huffman Code:

```
A: 0  
B: 01  
C: 11  
D: 110  
E: 111
```

What I'm thinking is that it is not valid, because A, or 1, would infringe on B, or 01. I'm not positive though. Could someone enlighten me on this?

Edit: I'm sorry I meant to type A as 0 and not 1.

Comment: Very invalid. A is a prefix of C and D and E, C is a prefix of D and E. A and B are fine together though.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a typo. A is actually 0, not 1. Thank you for your quick answer as well! Would A: 0 still hold?

Comment: Still invalid, you wouldn't be able to tell if `00111` is `AAE` or `ABC` and `110` could be eiter `D` or `CA`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No. A Huffman code is a prefix code, which means that no code can be a prefix of any other code. In your example, A is a prefix of B, and C is a prefix of both D and E.

A valid prefix code would be:

```
A: 0
B: 10
C: 11
```

That's as far as you can go with codes of length 1, 2, and 2. Any other codes would be a prefix of those. It is not possible to have a prefix code with lengths 1, 2, 2, 3, and 3.

This is a valid prefix code for five symbols:

```
A: 0
B: 10
C: 110
D: 1110
E: 1111
```

as is this:

```
A: 00
B: 01
C: 10
D: 110
E: 111
```