# How do i determine given code is decodable or not?

Tags: data-structures, huffman-code

How can I have given Huffman code decode and is it valid code or not?  Determine whether the following codes are uniquely decodable. Can you explain how do the answers take?

I. 0, 01, 11, 111

ii. 0, 10, 110, 111

Comment: The first is definitely not a Huffman code

Comment: How can you recognized it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444446/valid-huffman-codes

Comment: With the bit strings given, drawing the Huffman tree is straightforward. If each bit string ends on a separate leaf node, then it is a valid Huffman code.